# How do you redirect requests to a different host?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, mod-rewrite, redirect, host

Basically I want to create a situation where files served from my /cdn directory to use my cdn host rather than the local host.

How can I do this with apache rewrite?

I tried this but it doesnt work =/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cdn
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}      ^.*\.dev\.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}      ^.*\.qa\.*$ 
RewriteRule ^/cdn/(.*)           http://www1.mycdn.com/$1
RewriteEngine Off
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: i didnt see anything in there that answered my question, but thanks!

Comment: From the Matching Syntax part of that question `RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$    /newblog/$1` which can be adapted to `RewriteRule ^/cdn/(.*)$    http://cdn.example.com/$1`

Comment: Just in case you haven't thought about it: you can also accomplish this using mod_proxy, which is the better choice if you want to use a backend not reachable from the client for example.

Comment: @Chris Throw an [R] on there ;).  Redirection isn't much more than a footnote in the mega-answer there, so I kinda buy that argument.  I'd suggest the `Redirect` directive; eg.: `Redirect /cdn http://cdnhost/path/to/redirect`

Comment: how about a regular answer guys?

Comment: @Shane, Doh! Thank you. @Codeninja, it's a dupe, it should be closed. Also, turning the RewriteEngine Off is going to make it not work...

Comment: @codeninja Get rid of all the extra stuff in there.  Your `RewriteBase` change and the `RewriteEngine Off` will both break it, and the regex conditions won't match any valid hostname (the way you have it makes the host end with one or more `.`s).  All you need is `RewriteEngine On` then `RewriteRule ^/cdn/(.*) http://www1.mycdn.com/$1 [R]`.  Alternatively, the `Redirect` that I suggested above will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got contradictory stuff just in the code you posted. You have to leave the `RewriteEngine` on, you can't go turning it off at the end of the file or the server won't do aything. Also You can't set `RewriteBase` and then reference that folder in your matches later, so drop that rule too.

Other than that, it looks like several people have commneted with using just a `Redirect` instead, and one person gave you a cleaned up `RewriteRule` method.